# Handling Nested ViewPager swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am in a need of nested viewPagers, I am using a custom vertical viewPager where its child is a viewPager.

My problem is when the user swipes in vertical direction (Y axis) parent viewpager should function and if he swipes in horizontal (X axis) child viewpager has to function.

I came across a lot of tutorial where I can disable either parent's swipe or child's swipe but I dont want to do that, instead according to the swipe direction either parent (vertical) should work and child (horizontal) has to work.

I have also attached parent's viewpager adapter code here

```
class VerticalPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
{
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public VerticalPageAdapter(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
    {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        mVerticalViewPagerPosition = position;
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.homelayout_verticalpager, container, false);

        mPager = (ViewPagerTest)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new NewsPageAdapter(mContext));
        mPager.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        mPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Please help to sort out this.

Comment: You need to do something like this: http://codetheory.in/using-a-scrollable-viewgroup-in-a-scrollview/ solution described is to pass in the scroll state to the child and let the child handle it. It may not work for you though and you may need to enhance the code even further since you want to make sure that if the scroll direction is horizontal, the parent view pager should handle the swipe but if it's vertical, the child should handle it (or the other way around depending on how you've setup your view pagers). There's nothing built in that will do it for you.